# Android Studio 3.1.2 logcat won't stop spamming information

Tags: android, android-studio, logcat

This just started happening recently and it has gotten progressively worse. I was initially alerted when I saw a couple calls to the Facebook API when my app had nothing to do with FB whatsoever.

Things I tried that (temporarily) helped:
 - Closing all tabs in Chrome
 - Closing all open applications
 - Selecting "Show only selected application" option

**Note**. My app isn't even running. This happens as soon as I open Android Studio and plug my phone in. I get roughly 1,000 log/30 minutes.

Example 1

[image: example 1]

Example 2

[image: example 2]

```
08-11 13:08:53.087 2099-2099/? I/wpa_supplicant: RRM: Ignoring radio measurement request: Not RRM network
08-11 13:08:53.566 1626-1626/? D/HeadsetPhoneState: sendDeviceStateChanged. mService=1 mIsSimStateLoaded=true mSignal=2 mRoam=0 mBatteryCharge=4
08-11 13:08:55.629 1105-1142/? I/WifiService: requestActivityInfo uid=1000
08-11 13:08:55.630 1105-1142/? I/WifiService: reportActivityInfo uid=1000
    getSupportedFeatures uid=1000
08-11 13:08:55.636 1954-1954/? E/QtiImsExtUtils: getConfigForPhoneId phoneId is invalid
    isCarrierConfigEnabled bundle is null
08-11 13:09:12.433 2453-2453/? I/clatd: Detecting NAT64 prefix from DNS...
08-11 13:09:12.658 1751-1789/? I/QcrilOemhookMsgTunnel: [0]processOemHookIndication length=21
08-11 13:09:12.659 1751-1751/? D/QcrilMsgTunnelIfaceManager: handleMessage what = 0
08-11 13:09:12.665 15401-15415/? V/QMI_OEMHOOK: Thread=ModemService received { when=0 what=0 obj=android.os.AsyncResult@862fe81 target=com.qualcomm.qcrilhook.QmiOemHook }
```

---

```
08-11 13:05:00.210 2554-2554/? I/BeaconBle: Starting scan on OS scanner. BT state: 12
08-11 13:05:00.212 2554-2554/? D/BluetoothAdapter: isLeEnabled(): ON
08-11 13:05:00.214 1105-1795/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 25103:com.cvs.launchers.cvs/u0a161 for broadcast com.cvs.launchers.cvs/com.ibm.mce.sdk.wi.AlarmReceiver
08-11 13:05:00.215 1105-1541/? D/RecurrenceRule: Resolving using anchor 2018-08-11T13:05:00.215-04:00[America/New_York]
08-11 13:05:00.217 1626-2168/? I/bt_stack: [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1004)] GATT_Register
    [INFO:gatt_api.cc(1027)] allocated gatt_if=5
08-11 13:05:00.218 2554-18778/? D/BluetoothLeScanner: onScannerRegistered() - status=0 scannerId=5 mScannerId=0
08-11 13:05:00.221 1105-1541/? D/RecurrenceRule: Cycle 18 from 2018-07-19T00:00-04:00[America/New_York] to 2018-08-19T00:00-04:00[America/New_York]
08-11 13:05:00.222 1105-1541/? D/NetworkStats: Resolving plan for NetworkTemplate: matchRule=MOBILE_ALL, subscriberId=311480..., matchSubscriberIds=[311480...]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your selecected filter `Show only selected application` will only work if a process is selected. Just select your process when your app is running where it currently says `No Debuggable Processes`.

The output shown in your screenshot is the log of the whole device, including logs of the system and other apps.

Comment: I've been using Android Studio regularly for almost 2 years now. This was never an issue until about 1 week ago. What changed?

Comment: It usually autoselects your process, so you don't see this behaviour. But I don't think anything changed, you probably just never had the logcat open without having run your app first.

Comment: I have logcat open more often than not, and I _always_ clear the log between runs. I don't see how I could have been oblivious to this behavior for nearly 2 years.

Comment: I don't know why you haven't noticed it, but it's certainly not new. Also note that clearing the log does not affect this at all.

Answer (score 0):

Logcat shows logs in general, so if you want to see just specific app, you got app filter above the list. Also theres text filter if given app is too noisy as well